# Android NDK: File Upload using NDK

Tags: android, c++, c

Is there any source code for uploading a file from SD to a server using NDK? or any other method to upload a large size file without getting

```
Out Of Memory Exception
```

if so plz provide me the link?

The Code below is the one which i used and i got  Out Of Memory Exception

```
 private void UploadFileByClient(LocalFileVO localFileVO){


        try{

            File uploadFile = new File(
                    (localFileVO.getFolderPath() + "/" + localFileVO.getFileName()));

            HttpClient    client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            final HttpResponse resp; 
            final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
            final HttpPut post = new HttpPut("https://qa2-talos-vip-mexico.symnds.com/fileservice/files/");
            post.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mexico/1.0.0.57/android");
            post.setHeader("Content-Type", localFileVO.getMimeType());
            post.setHeader("Authorization", TOKEN);
            post.setHeader("x-mexico-endpointid", GUID);
            post.setHeader("x-mexico-filehash", localFileVO.getFileHash());
            post.setHeader("x-mexico-filesize", localFileVO.getSize());

            if (!TextUtils.equals("0", localFileVO.getFolderId()))
                post.setHeader("x-mexico-folder", localFileVO.getFolderId());

            post.setHeader("x-mexico-filename", localFileVO.getEncodedFileName());
            post.setHeader("Expect", "100-continue");
            post.setHeader("x-mexico-modtime",
                    String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));



//          ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = this.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(Uri.parse(uploadFile.getAbsolutePath()), "r"); 
//          InputStream in = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(uploadFile.getAbsolutePath()));
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);

            CountingInputStreamEntity entity = new CountingInputStreamEntity(in, uploadFile.length()); 
            entity.setUploadListener(this);
            post.setEntity(entity); 
            resp = httpClient.execute(post); 
            if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
                System.out.println("=======================Got the response from server============================");
            }


        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("==============Failed using HttpClient================="+e.getMessage());
        }

    }

   private int uploadFile( LocalFileVO localFileVO) throws IOException {


       UploadFileByClient(localFileVO);

      if(true){
          return 0;
      }

        File uploadFile = new File((localFileVO.getFolderPath() + "/" + localFileVO.getFileName()));


        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

        int     code = 0;
        try{

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection; 

        URL url = new URL("https://qa2-talos-vip-mexico.symnds.com/fileservice/files/");
    //  URL url = new URL("https://zpi.nortonzone.com/fileservice/files/");

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", url.getHost());
        // urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    //  urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
        urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(Integer.parseInt(localFileVO.getSize()));
        //urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mexico/1.0.0.57/android");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", localFileVO.getMimeType());
        //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", localFileVO.getSize());
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", TOKEN);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("x-mexico-endpointid", GUID);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("x-mexico-filehash", localFileVO.getFileHash());
        //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("x-mexico-filesize", localFileVO.getSize());

        if (!TextUtils.equals("0", localFileVO.getFolderId()))
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("x-mexico-folder", localFileVO.getFolderId());

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("x-mexico-filename", localFileVO.getEncodedFileName());
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Expect", "100-continue");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("x-mexico-modtime",
                String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));

        bufferOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream(),BSIZE);
    //  CountingOutputStream cOutStream = new CountingOutputStream(bufferOutputStream);

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try{
            int totalSize = 0;

             while (true) {
                   synchronized (chunks) {
                        int amountRead = fileInputStream.read(chunks);
                        System.out.println("========amount read========="+amountRead);
                        if (amountRead == -1) {
                              break;
                        }
                        bufferOutputStream.write(chunks, 0, amountRead);
                        bufferOutputStream.flush();
                  }
             }
            System.out.println("================================TotalSize " + totalSize);
            bufferOutputStream.flush();
             bufferOutputStream.close();
             fileInputStream.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("=============================================Writing time ==========================================================" + (endTime - startTime)); 
        //code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        InputStream inputStream  = urlConnection.getInputStream();



    long endTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time to get the response is  " + (endTime1 - endTime)); 
    // progressBar.setProgress(100);
        System.out.println("=================Response code is ================="+code);
        urlConnection.disconnect();
        //fileInputStream.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("========================Exception occured=================="+e.getMessage());
        }
        return code;

    }
```

Thank u

Comment: And, What have you tried so far ?

Comment: i tried using SDK ie Fileinputstream and bufferedoutputstream to read and write.. Using this only i got **OUT OF MEMORY EXCEPTION** ( tried to upload 20MB zip file)

Comment: Good, you should upload that code, so we can help you better dear :)

Comment: i edited my question with the code

Comment: ok, also upload error log, if you have any.

Comment: The class CountingInputStreamEntity - where does that come from?

Answer (score 0):

Your don't need NDK for this. Without your code I can only suggest that there are code for reading whole file into buffer. It is wrong. Do something like:
read files by small parts and sent these parts one by one into output stream (get it from connection)

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) )
..
URL url = new URL(urlServer);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// Allow Inputs & Outputs
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);

// Enable POST method
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
....
outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
....
// Read file
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

while (bytesRead > 0)
{
outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
}

outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

// Responses from the server (code and message)
serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

fileInputStream.close();
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: sir i have a doubt.. This code wont show any **Out Of Memory Exception ?** bcoz iam trying to upload a very big file of size around Min 20 MB - Max 150 MB

Comment: I`don't have working sample here, but application based on this approach working fine with uploading video files. If I remember correctly it was googled some time ago, I re-find this sample here http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/03/29/uploading-audio-video-or-image-files-from-android-to-server/

Comment: sir code is wrkng fine for 5MB file, but when i use 20MB file the app is getting crashed.. Help me

Answer (score 0):

Seems you missed setChunkedStreamingMode(int) call
from:http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html
Posting Content
To upload data to a web server, configure the connection for output using setDoOutput(true).
For best performance, you should call either setFixedLengthStreamingMode(int) when the body length is known in advance, or setChunkedStreamingMode(int) when it is not. Otherwise **HttpURLConnection will be forced to buffer the complete request body in memory** before it is transmitted, wasting (and possibly exhausting) heap and increasing latency.

But your content is too big to be buffered.

Comment: sir i could not understand the term **body length** (when the body length is known in advance)..Are u specifying the size of the file

Comment: sir i tried setChunkedStreamingMode(1000*1024) but still same error.